# django form error messages not showing

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-errors

So I have my view:

```
def home_page(request):
    form = UsersForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UsersForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    c.update({'form':form})
    return render_to_response('home_page.html', c)
```

my forms.py:

```
class UsersForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        widgets = {'password':forms.PasswordInput()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super( UsersForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[ 'first_name' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="First Name"  
        self.fields[ 'last_name' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Last Name"
        self.fields[ 'password' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Password"
```

and my template:

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.first_name }} {{form.last_name }} <br>
        {{ form.password }} <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
    </form>

    {% if form.errors %}
        {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p> {{ errors }} </p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <p> {{ error }} </p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Now, keep in mind that before I split the form field, my form just looked like this:

```
    <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
    </form>
```

and if the form had a problem (like if one of the fields was missing) it would automatically give an error message. After I split up the form fields in the template (made {{ form.first_name }}, {{ form.last_name }} and {{ form.password }} their own section) it stopped automatically giving error messages. Is this normal?

But the main problem is, how come my {{ if form.errors }} statement is not working / displaying error messages if there are error messages? For example, if I purposely not fill out a field in the form and I click submit, the database does not get updates (which is a good thing) but it does not give any error messages. Any idea why?

I also tried remove the {{ forms.non_field_errors }} and tried to return just field errors like so:

```
    {% if form.errors %}
        {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p> {{ errors }} </p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you fix the indentation in your view method and show exactly how your view code looks ?

Comment: whoops, okay there, just fixed it.

Comment: Also check inside `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`. Put it outside `{% if form.errors %}`. [Example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template).

Comment: Hm okay I removed the {{ forms.non_field_errors }} completely and it still doesn't work. I updated the post and showed what I tried.

Comment: @user2719875 removing it was not what I meant, but good to see that it's solved. Put back the non field errors though. Put it back outside the if block. Might come handy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the mistake (typo).

The snippet should be:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p> {{ error }} </p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I had `errors` instead of `error`.

Answer (score 5):

you have to send your form context again if is_valid() isn't true,

```
    if form.is_valid():

        return redirect('/user/contact/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'users/contact.html', context={'form': form})
```

because your errors will display in your form 
else: it will return ValueError

Answer (score 2):

Add this snippets in views.py like this

```
if request.method == "POST":
    fm = UserRegsitrationForm(request.POST)
    if fm.is_valid():
        fm.save()

    else:
        fm = UserRegsitrationForm()
    context = {'fm':fm}
    return render(request,'registration.html',context)
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: if your form is valid it will just save the form otherwise it will go to the else part and return form with errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error capture could very well have been done with:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.errors }}
{% endfor %}
```